# Same api endpoint for different users e.g user and admin in asp.net mvc / asp .net core mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, rest, asp.net-core

I am reading about how should I design my rest API endpoint for different users. while searching I found a concept of content negotiation on StackOverflow, where someone suggests using different media types like this
`application/vnd.example.contactsummary+json` and
`application/vnd.example.profilesummary+json`

See the accepted answer [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/390956/are-different-endpoints-to-display-the-same-resource-in-different-ways-restful) for more clarification.

Now I am a little bit confused and I didn't found any answer to questions that arise in my mind.

1. If the endpoint is the same. does it mean that we have the same action method in a controller to handle two different requests e.g for admin and user?
2. If we use different action methods then how should we create routes on the basis of headers in .net? as I found the solution of PHP framework [here](https://medium.com/@bpolaszek/expose-a-rest-api-to-different-kinds-of-users-with-api-platform-part-1-4-713f3c6db86f)
3. If we're creating different actions then why not use different routes e.g `/admin/courses` and `/courses`, what my understanding is that we use the same route for different users because we want a single get/post/put or patch method for one resource to keep API consumption easy
4. And if we're using different actions for the same route. should we create them in the different controller for the sake of Separation of concerns?

Comment: 1 - yes 2 - convert headers to route values (because only route values can be put in route pattern or path) 3 - at the model binding phase, it does not care the input values come from route values or headers, all can be used to build the required view model. So you can put the user role as a route value (use separate routes) or put it in a header (use same route). As long as you want to make it semantically clear (when looking at the URL), you need to follow the restful rule to decide which way it should go. The first link you shared is more resource-oriented but your case may not be so.

Comment: @KingKing So what is more restful? different headers or routes? and if we use the same action for different requests isn't it violate SOC? and it can grow larger if we add another role to the application?

Comment: I think using different routes is more restful (so you can know what it does almost obviously by just looking at the URL). If you use the same action, of course that should be a switcher (or some kind of delegator) especially when there are many cases to switch. Each case can be processed by a separate method or handler which targets a specific case. So it depends on how you organize it to ensure SOC. For the role of the switcher, you can introduce something like a provider that provides the actual handler to continue processing (similar to some patterns used in `asp.net core`).

Comment: @KingKing Thanks. btw my main concern is to follow some restful standard and as I had guess there's not any standard to solve this problem so now I can use any which suits me more.

Comment: yes, following standards is good to support a wide range of clients in the most friendly way, but it's not strictly required as long as you can understand its scope as well as its clients.